# Button Colour Doesn't Change in Function (Python tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a function which is called on a keypress, it changes the `bg` to orange, waits 1 second then changes it to green. The issue is that the button only waits one second then changes to green.

Why does it skip the first colour change (I assume the function runs through and the visual aspect of the colour change relies on returning to the mainloop, i.e. the mainloop waits and doesn't change (and thus the button colour also) until the end of the function)? What ways around this are there (Python 3.3 windows)?

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep

r = tk.Tk()

l = tk.Label(text = 'press f to make button flash')
l.pack()

b = tk.Button(text = 'useless button')
b.pack()

def flash(event):
    b.config(bg = 'orange')
    sleep(1)
    b.config(bg = 'green')

r.bind("<KeyPress-f>", flash)

r.mainloop()
```

Thankyou in advance (and sorry for the bad variable names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change will not take effect until the callback returns.

You need to call [`update`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update-method) or [`update_idletasks`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update_idletasks-method) to force update:

```
def flash(event):
    b.config(bg = 'orange')
    b.update_idletasks()
    sleep(1)
    b.config(bg='green')
```

BTW, using `time.sleep`, UI will not response. Consider using [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) (Another benefit: no need to call `update`, `update_idletasks`):

```
def flash(event):
    b.config(bg='orange')
    b.after(1000, lambda: b.config(bg='green'))
    # OR  b.after(1000, b.config, {'bg': 'green'})
```

Comment: Yep that works, I should've tried `after` first really, but good answer thanks!